# Sybase Replication rs_subcmp can ignore length?

Tags: replication, sybase

I want to use rs_subcmp utility to sync one table.
I've created a config file but I got the following error:

```
Length mismatch for column #9 between the primary (50) and the replicate (100). [c/subcmp.c(3398)]
Found 1 inconsistencies between the primary and the replicate - exiting ... [c/subcmp.c(3483)]
```

Is it possible to make rs_subcmp ignore this?
I want the column table bigger on the replicate side but this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If you're replicating the data, why does the field need to be bigger on the destination side?

Comment: The character set is different. We'll correct and put the same character set on both servers in the future.

Comment: May want to try this over at the SAP community network. Some of the RS engineers frequent there  http://scn.sap.com/community/sap-replication-server